# PHPTAL: Viewmodel Solution

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, phptal

I've picked up PHPTAL (after coming from PHPMustache), and I'm trying to inject a ViewModel class Mustache-style into my template. Let me explain ..

**controller**

```
$viewmodel = new \Viewmodel\Home();
$template = new \PHPTAL('application/views/home.html');
$template->viewmodel = $viewmodel;
echo $template->execute();
```

**home.html** <- template

```
<p>Hello <strong>${viewmodel/test}</strong>.</p>
```

**Home.php** <- viewmodel class

```
namespace Viewmodel;
class Home {
    function test() {
        return "world";
    }
}
```

---

The above *works*, but how do I avoid prefixing every variable reference with *"viewmodel/"*?

With Mustache, your variable context could be a single class. eg. `echo $template->render($html, $viewmodel);`. Prefixing is not necessary. All the *meat* is inside a loosely coupled viewmodel. I'd like to enforce this behaviour with PHPTAL without having to explicitly assign the whole class to a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

There's no equivalent to JavaScript's `with(model){}` operator. You're supposed to be explicit what variables you declare via `$context->set()` and use models explicitly, e.g. `${user/name}` rather than `${name}`. The latest version (in GitHub) supports closures, so you can use that for lazily computed variables.

If you're not giving direct access to models and you want to proxy *all* data through the viewmodel, then that looks like impedance mismatch with Moustache design philosophy.

In PHPTAL's approach to MVC you have business logic handled by model/controller (e.g. customer's account balance stored/manipulated) and any view-specific logic (e.g. if balance is negative then display it in red) goes into the template.

There's no in-between object to mediate that communication to add expressiveness to the template, because the template language is more expressive, and can be extended with TALES expressions:

```
<strong tal:condition="customer/isInDebt"/>

<strong tal:condition="isNegative:customer/balance"/>
```